# Asp.net 4.0 Display diffrent menu items depending on access level

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

NET4.0, i want to know how to hide some menu from web.site (e.g: new user and parameter) base on different access level.

Answer (score 1):

i Suggest you to read asp.net membership and Role provider. 
follow these links

[Asp.net membership and role provider](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx)

[Walkthrough for asp.net roles and membership](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/342061/Understanding-ASP-NET-Roles-and-Membership-A-Begin)

some thing like this. code taken from MSDN

```
if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "Administrators"))
    {
      Label1.Text = "You are not Adminstrator , not authorized to view user roles.";
      yourMenu.Visible = false;
}
```